# How to use iOS 5 remote notification banner confirm

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, ios5, banner

How to use iOS 5 remote notification banner to confirm notifications. I want to go to a specific view after select the banner item and remove the item from the banner.

Welcome you advices.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have controller over the notfication in the notification center. 
Meaning you can not remove the notification, the system will do that for you.

If you want to go a specific you just fill the userInfo property of the push notification. Then in your app check the  userInfo propert and go the view(or viewcontroller) it needs to go to

Comment: Dose this mean I can only specify it on the push service which view to call. Or I can change it on the client? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Well if you only have the one view to which a push notification goed then you can just code it to go there. If you want to control the view to which the user is going then you will need to add the userinfo to the push service.